How can I launch an Xorg server on another tty?
I found this command, which lets me launch an Xorg on tty8
sudo systemd-run     --property PAMName=login     --property User="$user"     --property StandardInput=tty     --property TTYPath=/dev/tty8     sh -c 'chvt 9 && exec startx > /tmp/xorg_output.log 2>&1'

I issue this command over ssh, while LightDM is displayed on the screen, meaning I have not logged in.
Trying to interact with the Xorg on tty8 is not possible, as my keyboard and mouse are totally frozen.
If I chvt 7, then the mouse and keyboard are working again;)
I’m a bit confused about how I can troubleshoot this;) Any pointers? I'm on NixOS.
